# How can I safely convert an XLS sheet to an XML file without knowing the XLS file's sheet name?

Tags: c#, oledb, xls, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

I adapated code I found [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/xml-from-excel.htm) to convert XLS to XML like so:

```
try
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
    System.Data.DataSet ds;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
    String fullFilePath = @"C:\worldSeries2014\baltimoreOrioles.xls";
    MyConnection = new 
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
   Source='{0}';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fullFilePath));
    MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet0$]", 
      MyConnection);
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Product"); // I don't know what this does
    ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    MyCommand.Fill(ds);
    MyConnection.Close();
    ds.WriteXml(@"C:\MiscellaneousJones\os.xml");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

This works (the xml file is created, with the data from the first sheet on the xls file), as long as the .xls file being loaded has a sheet named "Sheet0"

If I use this line instead (which is what the sample code I started with has):

```
MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
```

...I get, "*Sheet1$ is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long*"

The dollar sign is apparently necessary, as if I use this:

```
MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet0]", MyConnection);
```

...I get, "*The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet0'*"

So, can I rely on "Sheet0" always being the name of the sheet to convert? I'm fairly certain I can't, so how can I use "sheet 0" (the first one) on each occasion, regardless of its name? Alternatively, is there a way to programmatically determine the sheet name and use that?

Comment: `If I use this line instead...` That appears to be the same line as in your first example. I assume that's supposed to be `Sheet1$` on that line?

Comment: Also this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names) might help if you want to retrieve the sheet names in an Excel file. [This](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q257819) also, see the section `Retrieve Data Source Structure (Metadata) from Excel`

Comment: Yes, a typo (fixed); thanks for the hot links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `TableSchema` you can extract the Worksheet names using OleDb.

```
dtSchema = conObj.GetOleDbSchemaTable( OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
```